# How to fix TypeError: Cannot set property 'proteinname' of undefined while using express-session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I am developing the module where I have to save the searched item in the session and then I can use that item's value in my other request but in doing so I am getting "TypeError: Cannot set property 'proteinname' of undefined" why am I getting this and how can I resolve it

app.js code:

```
const expsession = require('express-session')

app.use(expsession({secret: 'my secret', resave: false, saveUninitialized:false}));
```

protein.js code

```
const expsession = require('express-session')

router.post('/getsearchvalue',(req,res,next)=>{
    req.expsession.proteinname = req.body.proteinname;
    console.log("inside post")
    console.log(req.body.proteinname)
    res.render('searchresult')
})
```

Comment: you have to create `expsession` before you can set a property on it.

Comment: or you can set it to an object with the property set `req.expsession = { proteinname: req.body.proteinname };`

Comment: thanks this is solved but I am not able to access the req.expsession.proteinname in another route it is coming as undefined

Comment: Probably because, well.... it's a different request, so it can't magically have properties that you set on a different request. I'm not that familiar with `express-session` but it's out of scope for posting here...

Comment: If this was solved without any apparently helpt, please delete the question. If you have a different problem now, and you think you need help after spending the time trying to find the solution. please post a new question.